# How do I fix "method does not override any method from its superclass."?

Tags: ios, uitableview, overriding

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

    cell.accessoryType = restaurantIsVisited[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None

    // Circular image
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am getting conflict error if i remove override from editActionsForRowAtIndexPath functions

Comment: You most likely have a typo in your method signature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove `override` word from your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` and `commitEditingStyle` function declarations.

Comment: nope that doesn't help. @commiteditingstyle it fixes it for me to add and i need the over ride functions this is for sharing and deleting gestures

Comment: @Ebin, Your response doesn't make sense. `- tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` is a table view data source method, and `- tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` is a table view delegate method. Unless you are subclassing a view controller class that implements these methods, you do **not** want the override qualifier. Override tells the compiler that the parent class implements a method but that your subclass provides a different version of that method.

Comment: The error you are getting specifically tells you that the parent class does not implement the method(s). (You don't say which methods are giving the error.)

Comment: hi @DuncanC i have edited and added the whole code. please can u tell me what the issue is?

Comment: i want to add a share button by slide gesturing to the left. where more and delete button would be seen

Comment: override func tableview(tableview: UITableView, editctionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]{

    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

///this is where i have my issue

Answer (score 2):

You should share your full class. Although, it seems that you are NOT OVERRIDING any method from your base class. Simple remove the `override` keyword from your method, or identify the correct BaseClass in which an `Overridable` method with the same signature(that you want to override) exists and then properly use the `extends` keyword.

I think you should first google the terms: **MethodOverriding, BaseClass(or SuperClass)**

Comment: yup i did. editActionsForRowAtIndexPath doesn't have a superclass. I'm still getting an conflict error